# Explain this rsync script for me - Linux backups

Tags: linux, backup, rsync

I don't know Linux and even less about programming so pardon my ignorance.

I have this script and would like someone to explain the internals to me.

I understand that the syntax of:

```
30 1 * * * /root/dobackup.daily /shared/svnrepos WOWSERVER /shared/backup/svnrepos
```

does an rysnc backup at 1:30 of /shared/svnrepos on the server to the remote WOWSERVER and places it in the /shared/backup/snvrepos on the WOWSERVER.

However, I don't understand the "options/variables/etc" in the script and was hoping someone could break it down for me, please.

Here's the script:

```
#!/bin/sh

# This script does personal backups to a rsync backup server. You will end up
# with a 7 day rotating incremental backup. The incrementals will go
# into subdirectories named after the day of the week, and the current
# full backup goes into a directory called "current"
# tridge@linuxcare.com

# directory to backup

if [ $# != 3 ]; then
        echo "Syntax is \"dobackup.daily {LocalDir} {RemoteServer} {RemoteDir}\""
        exit
fi

#RDIR=/shared/backup/CADData
RDIR=$3

# excludes file - this contains a wildcard pattern per line of files to exclude
EXCLUDES=

# the name of the backup machine
#RSERVER=TESTSERVER
RSERVER=$2

#LDIR=/shared/CADData
LDIR=$1

# your password on the backup server
#export RSYNC_PASSWORD=XXXXXX


########################################################################

TODAY=`date +%A`
YESTERDAY=`date --date=yesterday +%A`

#TODAY=test3
#YESTERDAY=Monday

OPTS="--link-dest=../$YESTERDAY --timeout=999 -aAz"

        export PATH=$PATH:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin

        # the following line clears the last weeks incremental directory
#      [ -d $HOME/emptydir ] || mkdir $HOME/emptydir
#      rsync --delete -aAz -e 'ssh -c blowfish -i /root/.ssh/backup -ax -o ClearAllForwardings=yes' $HOME/emptydir/ $RSERVER:$RDIR/$BACKUPDIR/
#      rmdir $HOME/emptydir

        # now the actual transfer
        rsync $OPTS -e 'ssh -c blowfish -i /root/.ssh/4to5 -ax -o ClearAllForwardings=yes' $LDIR/ $RSERVER:$RDIR/$TODAY/
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- RDIR - Remote (backup) directory
- $3 - The third command line option (e.g. `command option1 option2 option3`)
- EXCLUDES - file names to exclude
- RSERVER - The remote server to back up to
- $2 - The second command line option (e.g. `command option1 option2`)
- LDIR - The local directory to back up
- $1 - The first command line option (e.g. `command option1 option2`)
- TODAY - Grabs the date from the `date` command
- YESTERDAY - Grabs yesterday's date from the `date` command
- OPTS - Command line options for rsync (check `man rsync`)
- export PATH - makes sure that the PATH environment variable contains the likely location of rsync
- $HOME - the home folder (/home/username) of the user running the script